# Lines missing in Excel sheet after download

Tags: javascript, excel, download, export-to-excel

## Screenshot of the Excel sheet

[image: Screenshot of the Excel sheet]

I have a table with id and I have used that id in the controller.
The controller code is given below.
The problem is after I download the table data, the lines in the Excel sheet are missing.

```
$scope.download = function() {

        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('Processingfee').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        });
        saveAs(blob, "Report1.xls");
    };
```

Comment: I have edited my post with a screen shot.Please have a look of the screen shot .

Comment: No its javascript..